# Prove that if $P[X\leq Y] =1$ then $E[X]\leq E[Y]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I would like to prove/disprove that following claim:

> Prove that if $P[X\leq Y] =1$ then $E[X]\leq E[Y]$

How can it be done?

Comment: Equivalent to "if $P(Y-X \ge 0)=1$ then $E[Y]-E[X] \ge 0$" which, since $E[Y]-E[X] =E[Y-X]$, is equivalent to "if $P(Z \ge 0)=1$ then $E[Z] \ge 0$"

Comment: On a set of full measure, $X \leq Y$ then the integrals will have the same inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega ,\Sigma ,P )$, and $$S=\{\omega\in\Omega\ \text{ such that }Y(\omega)\geq X(\omega)\}$$
Then $P(\Omega\backslash S)=P(X> Y)=0$, 
$$\begin{split}
E(Y)&=\int_{\Omega}Y(\omega)dP(\omega) \,\,\,\text {(by definition)}\\
&= \int_{S}Y(\omega)dP(\omega) + \int_{\Omega\backslash S}Y(\omega)dP(\omega) \\
&= \int_{S}Y(\omega)dP(\omega) + 0 \\
&\geq \int_{S}X(\omega)dP(\omega) \,\,\,\text {(by definition of $S$)} \\
&\geq E(X)
\end{split}$$

Comment: Your last inequality should be equality.

Comment: Well, depends on how you tabulate the equations. I agree that the last two expressions are equal, but when I tabulate inequalities like this, I carry over the last inequality sign. In other words, the inequality sign is between the RHS, and the original LHS, that is $E(Y)$.

Comment: As it is written, it is not wrong, as $=$ implies $\geq$ but it looks strange stylistically IMO considering you already have $\int_\Omega Y=\int_SY$ earlier. Put differently, if you are to write the same argument "horizontally": $$E(Y)=\int_\Omega Y=\int_SY\geq\int_SX=\int_\Omega X=E(X),$$ then having $\geq$ in the next-to-last step just looks off.